# How to remove currencyMask's "0.00" format and just let users input any number?

Tags: angular, typescript

In angular, currencyMask helps me format my input payment in commas etc.. compared to using type=number. But the problem I am encountering is that currencyMask gives me a default value of $0.00. When entering 1, it'll become $0.01 rather than just 1. I hope I'm making sense so far. So rather than making it $0.01 I want the users to be able to enter whatever amount they wish and continue to have the comma formater and number only filter that currencyMask provides.

I have tried making type = "number". It works and my POST seems to be unaffected by the warning it gives when a decimal is entered: "value must be between whole number". But comma formatter is gone.  Below is the code that works but doesn't have comma formatter.

```
<input matInput type = "number" placeholder = "00000.00"
       [ngModel]= "paymentUpdate" 
       (ngModelChange) = "element.Payment = $event" 
       (keydown.Enter)="submitClick(element)">
```

I wish to have users enter a payment and include a decimal if they wish. CurrencyMask forces user to start from cents. I have never used a custom directive so if that's the only solution please show me extra steps..

Comment: I'm not sure whether I got what you want to do. Is `currencyMask` a directive? Like a 3rd party library? Or a directive you are building?

Comment: @jpavel no. I don't know how to build a custom directive so if that's a solution you're gonna suggest then I would need extra steps. The currencyMask is a built in angular thing..

Comment: Oh, I'm afraid, there's no such a thing like a `currencyMask` for `<input>` in angular. As a suggestion (since you don't wanna build your own directive): take a look at https://github.com/text-mask/text-mask/tree/master/angular2

Answer (score 0):

If we set default value as null. Then $0.00 default value won't get defaulted.

```
 myPrice: new FormControl(null, [Validators.required]),
```